# Static or Non static is more prefable for adding variables on string builder?

Tags: c#

Forgive me i am new in c#. I need to create a class which it will populating a string builder with values. So i can make this with two approaches.

```
 public class QrCode
 {

     private static StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();
     public static void PopulateString(int value1,int value2,decimal value3)
     {
         str.Append(value1 + "|" + value2 + "|" + value3 + "|");
     } 

     public static void Init()
     {
         str.Clear();
     }

     public static string GetResult()
     {
         return str.ToString();
     }

 }
```

Also inside my Form i am using this.

```
QrCode.Init();  
for(int a = 0; i<=grid.RowsCount; i++)
QrCode.PopulateString(
  Convert.ToInt32(grid.GetFocusedRowCellValue("value1")),
  Convert.ToInt32(grid.GetFocusedRowCellValue("value2")),
  Convert.ToDecimal(grid.GetFocusedRowCellValue("value3"))
);
var result=QrCode.GetResult();
//rest of my code
```

The second approach is to use non static fields Example:

```
public class QrCode
 {

     private StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();
     public void PopulateString(int value1,int value2,decimal value3)
     {
         str.Append(value1 + "," + value2 + "," + value3 + ",");
     } 
 }
```

And inside my Form:

```
 var qrCode = new QrCode();
 for(int a=0; i<=grid.RowsCount; i++)
   qrCode.PopulateString(
    Convert.ToInt32(grid.GetFocusedRowCellValue("value1")),
    Convert.ToInt32(grid.GetFocusedRowCellValue("value2")),
    Convert.ToDecimal(grid.GetFocusedRowCellValue("value3"))
  );
  var result=qrCode.GetResult();
   //rest of my code
```

So my question is, which of two is better practise to use? Also which one has better performance, and which one keeps less memory. Both of methods are working very well! I am just looking for the best approach.

Comment: Those are two very different things. Which one is "better" depends on how you want to use it. If you ever need to have two separate `QrCode`s, the static solution is more or less useless.

Comment: I want to have only one unique method for qrcode. I am just wondering if it is more painfull to keep all this static variables in memory.

Comment: I doubt if you want `StringBuilder` here, *string interpolation* seems to be enough `string result = $"{1},{2},{3.05m}";`

Comment: Well, they will stick around for the lifetime of the application. That _might_ become a pain, _might_ as well not. If you don't make it static, but have a reference that has a scope of app lifespan and instantiate only ever one, then there shouldn't be a difference, much.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Mind `str.Append`. The second call will append, not replace. So I don't think it is interchangeable.

Comment: Where and how do you access the data in the StringBuilder? Seems that you're just adding data but not using it.

Comment: There is no "pain" to memory. If you store a StringBuilder, it's always the same size.
With a static variable you define, "I want only one, exactly one, never zero never two stringbuilders". So you take out the fleixibility to have more than one Stringbuilder.
Sometimes you want to forbid to have more than one. (A singleton). That's about the only occasion you define it as static.

Comment: I am adding many values in StringBuilder, and after that i am sending this string into a database. Imagine a loop as the the example above.(Please check my modified question)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment above: If the following should work, then static is not an Option:

```
void doSomething()    
{
   QRCode code1 = new QRCode();
   QRCode code2 = new QRCode();

   code1.Populate("1,2,3");
   code2.Populate("4,5,6");

  // the content with the static implementation would now contain data from BOTH Populate calls - since the StringBuilder is 'shared' amongst instances.
}
```

Comment: Side note: `QRCode code1 = new QRCode("1,2,3");` (without `Populate(...)`) seems to be more natural

Comment: Sorry my question was little unclear, please check my modified question

Answer (score 0):

The append method of the StringBuilder class adds a new text to the string kept by the string builder.
So if you plan to have more than one instance of the QrCode class, then having this method static is en error, bacause 'str' for each new object will contain the text from previously created objects (static method + append produces an unintended text accumulator in this case).

According to the best practices you should always try to encapsulate the implementation - so meke methods non-static, unless you really (for explicit reasons/requirements) need to to have them static. Besides, making methods non-static (belonding to objects) saves a lot of trouble (e.g. thread safe).

If you worry about having only one version of the code - then don't. The non static method, event if instatiated many times, is wrtitten once and is kept in a single class.